# Applet cannot display in html in IE

Tags: java, appletviewer

I used appletviewer to verify my code. It is right.

When I use IE to display html including applet, why the IE just display the content from the html not from applet ? here is the code:

```
Java: 

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends java.applet.Applet{

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
  g.drawString("HelloWorld", 5, 25);
}
}


Html:
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello to Everyone</title>
</head>
<body >
<P>Why?
<APPLET CODE= "java.awt.Graphics.HelloWorldApplet" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25></APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition: I put the HelloWorldApplet.java and HelloWorldApplet.class and HelloWorldApplet.html fils in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

The `code` attribute doesn't look right.  Is your class really in a package called `java.awt.Graphics`?  `Graphics` is a class in the existing package `java.awt`.

It looks like your code is not in a package, so it should be `code="HelloWorldApplet.class"`.

Comment: I tried it again based on your suggestion. Another situation is that it appears an alert saying "blocked exception..."by using IE. So what is wrong with it ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: this code is an example from the book named "teach myself in java in 21 days". Actually, the code on the book is what you wrote. I made some change based on other infor.

Answer (score 0):

If your applet is in a different package other than the default, you'd want to use something like:  code="org.me.hello.MyApplet"

A good applet tutorial can be found at: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I am a beginner for Java learning. The code is an example from a java book.